# JSON file with different key names

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the MongoDb with the mongoose library. My schema is in English, but I am receiving a the same structure with German (or another) keywords.

MongoDB schema:

```
{
  "Uid": Number,
  "User": {
    "Firstname": String,
    "Lastname": String
  }
}
```

JSON Object:

```
"Uid": Number,
"Benutzer": {
  "Vorname": String,
  "Nachname": String
}
```

I am receiving the JSON Object as a string and I am working with JSON.parse, the realObject is more complex, I wouldn't like to copy field by field. In case the keywords are the same, I can use a simple assignment:

```
const my_object = JSON.parse(file_as_string)
MyObject.findOneAndUpdate(
  { UID: my_object.Uid},
  {
    User: my_object.Benutzer
  })
```

My question is: How do I convert the JSON (with the German keywords) into the schema with the English keywords?

Comment: Is the json (in german or any other langauge) always valid and has the same length/size? Or do you need verfiy the integrity? And why is the Uid in mongodb a string and in the json a number?

Comment: The JSON is valid an has the same length/size, Uid in mongodb and Uid in the JSON are booth a number, sorry for that.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How do I convert the JSON (with the german keywords) into the schema with the english keywords?

Comment: Post a full json example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would need to deepclone your object and translate the property names in the process.

```js
let translations = { 
      "Benutzer": "User", 
      "Vorname": "Firstname", 
      "Nachname": "Lastname", 
      "Strasze": "Street",
      "PLZ": "ZIP",
      "Ort": "City",
      "Nummer": "Number"
}


function deepClone(data) {
  //For arrays deepclone every element in the array  
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(d => deepClone(d));
  }

  //For object deepclone every property and translate the property's name
  //Fallback on the original name, if no translation is found
  if (typeof data === "object") {
    let result = {}
    for (let key in data) {
      result[translations[key]||key] = deepClone(data[key]);
    }
    return result;
  }

  //return primitive datatypes (number, string, bool) as they are
  return data;
}
    
let g = { 
  Uid: 1, //this one is not gonna be translated because there is no translation entry
  Benutzer: { 
    Vorname: "Papa", 
    Nachname: "Schlumpf", 
    Adressen: [  //this one is not gonna be translated because there is no translation entry
      { Strasze: "Hauptstraße", Nummer: 1, PLZ: "1234", Ort: "Schlumpfhausen" },
      { Strasze: "Hauptplatz", Nummer: 17, PLZ: "1235", Ort: "Gargamelsdorf" }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(deepClone(g));
```